# How to convert a Pandas data frame column from np.datetime64 to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I would like to put a Pandas Data Frame column into `datetime` format from `datetime64`. This works on an an individual basis. In particular the following works fine:

```
t = dt['time'].values[0]
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t.astype(int)/1000000000)
```

However, when I try to do this to the entire column

```
dt['datetime'] = dt['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.astype(int)/1000000000))
```

I get the following error:

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62578)()

```
<ipython-input-26-5950d82979b4> in <lambda>(x)
      1 print(type(dt['time'].values[0]))
      2 
----> 3 dt['datetime'] = dt['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.astype(int)/1000000000))
      4 t = dt['time'].values[0]
      5 print(t)

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert my column to `datetime` and/or make a new column in `datetime` format?

Here is the info for the dataframe:

[image: info]

Answer (score 8):

You can convert Series of dtype `datetime64[ns]` to a NumPy array of `datetime.datetime` objects by calling the `.dt.to_pydatetime()` method:

```
In [75]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 252 entries, 0 to 251
Data columns (total 1 columns):
time    252 non-null datetime64[ns]<--the `time` column has dtype `datetime64[ns]`
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 2.0 KB

In [77]: df.head()
Out[77]: 
        time
0 2009-01-02
1 2009-01-05
2 2009-01-06
3 2009-01-07
4 2009-01-08


In [76]: df['time'].dt.to_pydatetime()[:5]
Out[76]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 5, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 6, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 7, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 8, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

---

Note that NDFrames (such as Series and DataFrames) can only hold datetime-like objects as objects of dtype `datetime64[ns]`. The automatic conversion of all datetime-likes to a common dtype simplifies subsequent date computations. But it makes it impossible to store, say, Python `datetime.datetime` objects in a DataFrame column.  Pandas core developer, [Jeff Reback explains](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6741#issuecomment-39026803),

> "We don't allow direct conversions because its simply too complicated to keep anything other than datetime64[ns] internally (nor necessary at all)."

Comment: Thank you. This is getting me part of the way there, but I want this datetime to be a column of the original data frame. How do I do that if you are producing an array?

Comment: Pandas works very hard to ensure that datetime-like objects in a DataFrame are converted to `datetime64[ns]` dtype. This has the benefit of corralling disparate datetime-like objects into a single data type which is good for computations. But it does make it (I think) impossible to store datetime-like objects in a dtype other than `datetime64[ns]` in a DataFrame column. If you need to work with Python `datetime.datetime`s, you have to keep them in a variable outside the DataFrame.

Comment: The same issue arose [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31918181/190597) -- the OP wanted a Series of dtype `datetime64[D]` instead of `datetime.datetime`s but it was impossible for essentially the same reason.

Comment: Pandas core developer, [Jeff Reback says](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6741#issuecomment-39026803), "We don't allow direct conversions because its simply too complicated to keep anything other than datetime64[ns] internally (nor necessary at all)."

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the correct one. I spent A LOT of time trying to figure out why I can't change the DataFrame's column type from datetime64[ns] to datetime.datetime. Thanks for this information! @unutbu

Answer (score 0):

Without your data set, I have to guess at some things.  But, you should be able to repeat the same thing as what you demonstrated as having worked.

```
dt['datetime'] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt['time'].values.astype(int)/1000000000))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this also produces an error: 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'