# How to write pandas date column to Databricks SQL database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, azure-databricks

I have `pandas` dataframe column that has string values in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:mmmmmmm`, for example `2021-12-26 21:10:18.6766667`. I have verified that all values are in this format where milliseconds are in 7 digits. But the following code throws conversion error (shown below) when it tries to insert data into an Azure Databricks SQL database:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error and how can we fix it?

**Remark**: After conversion the initial value (for example `2021-12-26 21:10:18.6766667`) even adds two more digits at the end to make it `2021-12-26 21:10:18.676666700` - with 9 digits milliseconds.

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myDataFile.csv', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer')

data_df['OrderDate'] = data_df['OrderDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

data_df.to_sql(name='CustomerOrderTable', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'OrderID' : sq.VARCHAR(10), 
   'Name' : sq.VARCHAR(50),
   'OrderDate' : sq.DATETIME()})
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get this same error if you convert `data_df['OrderDate']` to a `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: @Simon If you mean `pd.to_datetime(data_df['OrderDate'])` , then yes exact same error. And in both cases it adds even two more digits `00` at the end to 7 digits milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Python `datetime.datetime`. Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354498/how-to-convert-a-pandas-data-frame-column-from-np-datetime64-to-datetime)

Comment: @Simon I'm new to python world. On `datetime.datetime(data_df['OrderDate'])`,  I get the error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`. It his is not what you meant please let me know, maybe, by giving a one liner code.

Comment: @tdy Thanks for clarifying. On `data_df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['OrderDate']).dt.to_pydatetime()`, I still get the exact same error. But the number of digits in milliseconds reduces to 6 from 7.

Comment: Try: `data_df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['OrderDate']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]`

Comment: @tdy Your suggestion worked perfectly (thank you). For the benefit of other users, you may want to convert your comment into a Response. And, I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @nam Great. After some more digging, I think it will actually work without converting `OrderDate` at all. In other words, load with `read_csv` and then directly save `to_sql` (without changing `OrderDate`).

Comment: @tdy In my case the raw data did not work. So, I used your second choice. But it's good that you mentioned another option as it may work for some other readers of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the dates as plain strings **without** converting `to_datetime`.

This is because [DataBricks SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/queries/query-results-external-data-source) is based on SQLite, and [SQLite expects date *strings*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime):

> In the case of SQLite, date and time types are stored as strings which are then converted back to `datetime` objects when rows are returned.

---

If the raw date strings still don't work, convert them `to_datetime` and reformat into a safe format using [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
```

Or if the column is already `datetime`, use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) directly:

```
df['OrderDate'] = df['OrderDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
```