# Python/Pandas: How do I convert from datetime64[ns] to datetime

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, datetime64

I have a script that processes an Excel file. The department that sends it has a system that generated it, and my script stopped working.

I suddenly got the error `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` for the following line of code:

```
df['DATE'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\._/-]', '')
```

I checked the type of the date columns in the file from the old system (dtype: object) vs the file from the new system (dtype: datetime64[ns]).

How do I change the date format to something my script will understand?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918181/3311213) but my knowledge about date formats isn't this granular.

Comment: You can convert dates back to strings with `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: That did it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

Comment: I do not know why this answer is accepted as I believe it maintains type datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `apply` function on the dataframe column to convert the necessary column to String. For example:

```
df['DATE'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Make sure to import `datetime` module.

`apply()` will take each cell at a time for evaluation and apply the formatting as specified in the `lambda` function.

Answer (score 8):

`pd.to_datetime` returns a Series of `datetime64` dtype, as described here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

```
df['DATE'] = df['Date'].dt.date
```

or this:

```
df['Date'].map(datetime.datetime.date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers here are outdated. I stumbled up on this issue and thought it is a bug in Pandas and raised an issue here.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52664

Turns out, `datetime64` is not a valid dtype at all. So, we have to convert it to any of the valid dtypes below.

- datetime64[s]
- datetime64[ms]
- datetime64[us]
- datetime64[ns]

In pandas below version 2, `s.astype('datetime64')` doesn't throw any error, simply ignores it. Starting with pandas 2.0.0, it throws an error.