# Convert pandas series datetime64[ns] to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'd like to convert a series from datetime64[ns] to datetime. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207640/python-pandas-how-do-i-convert-from-datetime64ns-to-datetime) and tried `pd.to_datetime` but it doesn't work.

example

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
d = {'id': ['A', 'B'], 'date':[datetime.utcnow(), datetime.utcnow()]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.dtypes
```

```
id              object
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Convert `date` to datetime

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

After converting, the dtype of `date` is still `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking `datetime64[ns]` is Pandas' datetime type. Why do you need `datetime.datetime`? They don't play well with Pandas as the series will be treated as object type.

Comment: use `df['date']=df['date'].dt.date`