# Date conversion doesn't work when creating new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

What I am  trying to do is convert my date to datetime64[D]. At source - Some of the dates are object type and some of the dates are datetime64[ns]. **I am not asking how to do the conversion** - I know it. But something's happening while I create a new column, and following code seems to have no impact and datetime64[ns] doesnt change.

```
 df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

This is the sample dataframe:

```
d = {'date' :['2015-10-05 15:08:43', '2015-10-05 19:17:12', '2015-10-06 15:51:22', '2015-10-06 19:39:18', '2015-10-06 19:58:06', '2015-12-18 11:09:01'], 'name': ['john', 'tom', 'phill', 'nero', 'bob', 'rob']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

date in df2 is object type. When we do the following

```
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

date becomes dtype: datetime64[ns].

Now following code works and produces datetime64[D] output

```
df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

But when I create a new column, it goes back to

```
df2['date'] = df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

See the output here -

**Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]**

So, my question is that why is it not working when I am creating a new column ?

Note: I know that last line produces warning. So I also tried below method but its not producing datetime64[D]

```
newcol = df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
df2.assign(date = newcol)
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is anything reverting back to `object`?

Comment: If you're referring to why the dtype if `datetime64[ns]` instead of `datetime64[D]` I found this other useful SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917964/python-numpy-cannot-convert-datetime64ns-to-datetime64d-to-use-with-numba

Comment: date goes back to datetime64[ns] even after using df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')   @roganjosh

Comment: Just seen the link you've been given. I had no idea about that at all. More wonky datetime fun with pandas :)

Comment: @Orenshi I have seen that link - but not solving my problem.

Comment: From what I can infer in the other link, it seems like because you're assigning it back to a column (aka a new column in a DataFrame is a Pandas Series), you're kind of stuck with `datetime64[ns]` :(

Comment: Oops, that's awful. Same thing was happening when I tried df2['date'].dt.floor('d') .But isn't that weird - if you cant change or create a column ?

Comment: Hmmm, from your last comment; you know that `df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')` doesn't work in-place at all? You have to assign the results back to something, or the change is thrown away. That's part of the reason I was struggling to read your question flow

Comment: @singularity2047 although you point out an interesting fact that datetime object are always `datetime64[ns]` in pandas by opposition to numpy where you can have `datetime64[D]`, I'm not sure I understand the problem you have. And actually it makes sense that `df2['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')` give you `dtype='datetime64[D]'` because this is a numpy.ndarray and not a column of a DF anymore :)

Comment: " because this is a numpy.ndarray and not a column of a DF anymore " -  I realized that after you pointed out.  I wanted to have the dates in datetime64[D] type. But as you pointed out thats not possible as long as I am using a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Reback, a pandas developer, [wrote the following in 2014](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6741#issuecomment-39026803) (and I think it still stands)

> We don't allow direct conversions because its simply too complicated
> to keep anything other than datetime64[ns] internally (nor necessary
> at all). It could be done, but not very useful IMHO.
>
> This is currently NotImplemented, but is very straightforward to do.

Therefore one may not be able to have dataframe columns as `datetime64[D]`, only as `datetime64[ns]`.

If one needs the column return  a Numpy representation of the column using [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and work with it, as following

```
dates = df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```