# Count business day between using pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have tried to calculate the number of business days between two date (stored in separate columns in a dataframe ).

```
    MonthBegin  MonthEnd
0   2014-06-09  2014-06-30
1   2014-07-01  2014-07-31
2   2014-08-01  2014-08-31
3   2014-09-01  2014-09-30
4   2014-10-01  2014-10-31
```

I have tried to apply  `numpy.busday_count` but I get the following error:

```
Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I have tried to change the type into Timestamp as the following :

```
Timestamp('2014-08-31 00:00:00')
```

or datetime :

```
datetime.date(2014, 8, 31)
```

or to numpy.datetime64:

```
numpy.datetime64('2014-06-30T00:00:00.000000000')
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Note 1: I have passed tried `np.busday_count` in two way :
1. Passing dataframe columns, `t['Days']=np.busday_count(t.MonthBegin,t.MonthEnd)`

2. Passing arrays `np.busday_count(dt1,dt2)`

Note2: My dataframe has over 150K rows so I need to use an efficient algorithm

Comment: can you show how did you use `np.busday_count` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do is

`df.apply(lambda row : np.busday_count(row['MBegin'],row['MEnd']),axis=1)`

For my dataframe `df` as below:

```
      MBegin          MEnd
0   2011-01-01  2011-02-01
1   2011-01-10  2011-02-10
2   2011-01-02  2011-02-02
```

doing :

```
df['MBegin'] = df['MBegin'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
df['MEnd'] = df['MEnd'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
df['busday'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.busday_count(row['MBegin'],row['MEnd']),axis=1)

>>df

     MBegin         MEnd   busday
0   2011-01-01  2011-02-01  21
1   2011-01-10  2011-02-10  23
2   2011-01-02  2011-02-02  22
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917964/python-numpy-cannot-convert-datetime64ns-to-datetime64d-to-use-with-numba

Comment: `df["MonthBegin"] = df["MonthBegin"].values.astype('datetime64[D]')` might solve your problem

Comment: k. Thanks, It works and it is incredibly faster than any other algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `bdate_range`, also I corrected your input , since the most of MonthEnd is early than the MonthBegin

```
[len(pd.bdate_range(x,y))for x,y in zip(df['MonthBegin'],df['MonthEnd'])]
Out[519]: [16, 21, 22, 23, 20]
```

Comment: Since my dataframe has over 150K rows do you have a faster algorithm in your mind, this algorithm is really time consuming

Comment: @JeffTehrani `[np.busday_count(x[0],x[1]) for x in df.values.astype('datetime64[D]')]

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the template in which your dates are written.

```
 a = datetime.strptime('2014-06-9', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Calculate this for your

```
b = datetime.strptime('2014-06-30', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now their difference

```
c = b-a
c.days
```

which gives you the difference 21 days, You can now use list comprehension to get the difference between two dates as days.
will give you datetime.timedelta(21), to convert it into days, just use

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to get the desired result as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MonthBegin': ['2014-06-09', '2014-08-01', '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01'],
                   'MonthEnd': ['2014-06-30', '2014-08-31', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-30']})
df['MonthBegin'] = df['MonthBegin'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['MonthEnd'] = df['MonthEnd'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['BDays'] = np.busday_count(df['MonthBegin'].tolist(), df['MonthEnd'].tolist())
print(df)

  MonthBegin   MonthEnd  BDays
0 2014-06-09 2014-06-30     15
1 2014-08-01 2014-08-31     21
2 2014-09-01 2014-09-30     21
3 2014-10-01 2014-10-31     22
4 2014-11-01 2014-11-30     20
```

Additionally `numpy.busday_count` has few other optional arguments like weekmask, holidays ... which you can use according to your need.