# Calculating number of business days between two dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a following problem. I would like to calculate number of business days between two dates. Example:

```py
import numpy as np

pokus = {"start_date" : "2022-01-01 10:00:00" , "end_date" : "2022-01-01 17:00:00" }
df = pd.DataFrame(pokus, index=[0])
cas_df["bus_days"] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"]) , pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"]))
```

Which returns a confusing error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vojta/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3251, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-8910d714721b>", line 3, in <module>
    cas_df["bus_days"] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"]) , pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"]))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in busday_count
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cas_df["bus_days"] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"]).values.astype('datetime64[D]') , pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"]).values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

Comment: Works. Note that .to_numpy() is preferrable to .values()

Comment: @VladimirFokow depends what you want to do. If you don't need a copy `.values` is preferable, here this is the case as we don't keep the object after the call to `busday_count`. What shouldn't be done is `a = df['col'].values`, then try to modify `a`

Comment: @mozway, 1) well, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/14627505) explains why to always prefer `.to_numpy()` over `.values`, if I didn't miss something. 2) Plus, `.to_numpy()` has a parameter `copy=False` -- so it not always makes a copy. 3) And here, since we are casting to `'datetime64[D]'`, aren't we making a copy anyway?

Answer (score 2):

[`np.busday_count`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html)
accepts only `datetime64[D]`, but pandas Dataframes and Series can only hold `datetime64[ns]`, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918181/14627505).

So what we can do is convert the start and end date columns to a numpy array (as type `datetime64[D]`), and then pass these values to `np.busday_count`:

```py
days = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].to_numpy(dtype='datetime64[D]')
cas_df["bus_days"] = np.busday_count(days[:, 0], days[:, 1])
```

---

( you could also use `.to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]')` )