# How to fix pandas v2 "ValueError: Cannot convert from timedelta64[ns] to timedelta64[D]."

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, timedelta

When upgrading from pandas version 1 to 2.0.0, I suddenly get a `ValueError` in a script that worked fine before upgrading pandas to version 2:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert from timedelta64[ns] to timedelta64[D].
Supported resolutions are 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns'
```

This is a minimally reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'designation_date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02']})
df['recency'] = pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df['designation_date'])
df['recency'] = df['recency'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

What do I need to replace `df['recency'].astype('timedelta64[D]')` with so that the code works with pandas v2?

Using `astype('timedelta64[D]')` is used quite a bit in answers across SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918181/7483211).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `.dt.days` accessor instead of `astype('timedelta64[D])`:

```py
df['recency'] = df['recency'].dt.days
```

The change in behaviour from v1 to v2 is documented [here in the Pandas changelog](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8cf4ab491b06274f555d1ea305c172354208747a/doc/source/whatsnew/v2.0.0.rst#disallow-astype-conversion-to-non-supported-datetime64timedelta64-dtypes).

Answer (score 0):

df['recency'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['recency'])
df['recency'] = df['recency'].dt.days

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.